# "On the phone" or "over the phone" in context?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please if I have to use *on* or *over* in the following sentence?

> People tend to be nervous when they speak a foreign language **on**/**over** the phone.

Comment: Either sound acceptable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Either is fine, but as a rule of thumb "over" tends to be used more when the verb carries the idea of a prolonged exchange.

For example:

> We spoke *on* the phone. [[supporting ngram]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoke%20on%20the%20phone%2C%20spoke%20over%20the%20phone&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoke%20on%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspoke%20over%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0)
>
> We conduct business *over* the phone. [[supporting ngram]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=business%20on%20the%20phone%2Cbusiness%20over%20the%20phone&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbusiness%20on%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbusiness%20over%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score -1):

According to OLAD (the collocations with phone):

> They like to do business (***by* phone**)/ (***over the* phone**).